# What is the difference between local.properties file (in config directory) and project.properties file (in platform directory) in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I did my research but couldn’t  find the authentic answer.
Any  inputs from hybris experts highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Project properties is found within the platform directory of hybris and provides factory default settings. It is not recommended to edit this file.

Local properties is the working copy of the project.properties file that will be found in the config folder. Use this file to override the default hybris settings.

They both do the same thing, allow you to define database connections, ports, build environment, mail services, frontend https, etc,etc. You might ask why don't you just modify the project.properties file instead? You don't because of the following:

1. Migration aspects - you don't want to merge your changes into new versions of hybris every time you upgrade
2. Clustering aspects - you would need a unique project.properties for each cluster, that would be identical bar one change
3. Value Persistence - similar to migration, the values in project.properties tend to change every version, you'll overwrite your changes when upgrading
4. File Access Rights Aspects - the project.properties is stored in a different place, in a production environment you might not have access to the hybris platform
5. Overview Aspects - project.properties contains a huge number of properties, it's will be a lot harder to maintain this

In general any changes you want to make use local.properties in config. Hope that helps.

Comment: a bit Confused.  if  Project.Properties  contain more Properties, then how can the 2  Files do the same thing ... database connection, ports, build etc

Comment: BIG  THANKS for  the first  answer.   could you share 3 most important  properties  maintained by Project.Properties

Comment: Well the thing is anything within the project.properties you can change within the local.properties file, there is nothing stopping you really.

Like hybris runs its own tomcat which is configured in the project.properties. If you're happy running the default there is no need to change this, however there is nothing stopping you from configuring your own tomcat for example. Project.properties also handles logging, which again there isn't really too much need to change that unless you want something custom.

Just open up the project.properties and have a look what is in it.

Comment: They can be found within the project.properties file itself, just open it and have a look.

Comment: @Grinch91 `project.properties` file is found in each extentions not only in platform